# realloc(): invalid next size glibc detected

Tags: c, size, dynamic-arrays, realloc

I was implementing stacks using dynamically allocated arrays. Once the array is full I need to reallocate the array and make it twice as big as the initial array.

My code:

```
typedef int Item;
typedef struct stackImp *Stack;
struct stackImp{
    Item * items;
    int top;
    int maxSize;

Stack createStack (void){
    Stack s = malloc(sizeof(struct stackImp)); 
    assert(s != NULL);
    s->items = malloc(DEFAULT_SIZE * sizeof(Item));
    assert(s->items != NULL);
    s->top = 0; 
    s->maxSize = DEFAULT_SIZE;
    return s;

void push (Stack stack, Item item)
    .
    .
    .
    if (stack->top < stack->maxSize) { 

    //Over here I'm checking if the top index is less than the
    //maximum Items the array can store. If it's less then it pushes the
    //item to the top of the array.

    stack->items[stack->top] = item;
    stack->top++;
    }
    else {
    //If the index is greater than or equal to the maximum size then
    //I realloc a new array which is twice the size of the initial array.

    temp = realloc(stack->items, 2*(stack->maxSize) * sizeof(Item));
    assert (temp != NULL);
    stack->items = temp;
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

When I push items onto the stack it works perfectly fine but when I push on more than the initial maxSize it gives me this error: 
[image]

It is clear I'm doing something wrong with my realloc function but I am unable to find what.

This is the valgrind output: [image]

Comment: Run with debugger or valgrind.

Comment: @timrau I did run it with valgrind but I don't understand what it's saying and what I should be looking at.

Comment: Then you should attach the valgrind output by editing your question.

Comment: How do you initialize a `Stack`?

Comment: Could you compile with `-g` and run with valgrind again? This way you could identify which line the issues happen in.

Comment: @timrau I'm new to this so I don't know how to do that, could you please tell me how? Right now I type in "make" to compile the files

Comment: Uh, that depends on how your Makefile was written.

Comment: @timrau Hey so I changed the makefile and compiled it with -g and ran it with valgrind. It says invalid write of size 4 at (some memory address): push(arrayStack.c:40) and line 40 of my code is: 
stack->items[stack->top] = item;

Comment: Please show complete `push()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is coming from `realloc` and the memory arena seems to be *already* corrupted, it's almost certainly something you're doing *before* this point.

Your best bet is to run it with a memory debugger like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and check if you're overflowing buffers.

It may be the initial allocation of the array of `Item` objects (or lack thereof), it may be incorrect initialisation of the other fields like `top` or `maxSize`. Without the full code, it's a little hard for us to tell so, if you want a *definitive* answer, you should post *all* the relevant code.

But a memory debugger should help out greatly, should you not wish to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is kind of confusing, since stack->top does not actually points to the index of the actual stack top. This might be causing some confusion on other parts of your code, since you have to use stack->items[stack->top-1] and not stack->items[stack->top] to access the top of your stack.

Please double check things like that. This error is probably caused by memory corruption. Learn how to use memory debuggers.

And I recommend that you try to implement stacks using lists instead of arrays.